# Android: accessing the images that make up a video

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-camera

I'm making an app that takes a video and does some computation on the video. I need to carry out this computation on individual frames of the video. So, I have two questions:

1. Are videos in Android stored as a sequence of pictures? (I've seen a lot of Android devices that advertise having 25-30 fps cameras) If yes, can I, as a developer, get access to these frames that make up a video and how so?
2. If not, is there any way for me to generate at least 15-20 distinct frames per second from a video taken on an android device? (and of course, do the computation on those frames generated)

Answer (score 2):

Videos are stored as videos. To manipulate frames one can use FFMPEG library. There are FFMPEG ports to Android such as in Dolphin opensource player. This would require C/C++ programming with NDK though.